# Prove that if $x$, $y$, and $n$ are positive integers such that $x^{2024}$ + $y^{2024}$ = $2^n$ , then $x = y$.

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

Prove that if $x$, $y$, and $n$ are positive integers such that  $x^{2024} + y^{2024} = 2^n$ ,  then $x = y$.

My workings thus far:

I have proved the case $n=1$, in which $x = y = 1$.

For $n>1$, $2^n$ is divisible by $4$. Let a = $x^{1012}$ and $b = y^{1012}$. Hence, $a^2 + b^2 = 2n$.

Case 1:

When $a$ is even, $a^2 = (2m)^2 = 4 \cdot m^2 = 0 \pmod 4$.

However, I am now stuck on the case where $a$ is odd. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You haven't actually finished the case where $a$ is even. The case where $a$ and $b$ are odd is actually easier; just look at it modulo $4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us put $x=2^a\cdot c, y=2^b \cdot d,$ where $a$, $b$ are non-negative integers and $c$, $d$ are odd. The equation then becomes $$2^{2024a}c^{2024}+ 2^{2024b}d^{2024}=2^n.$$ Let us assume $a \leq b$, then we get $$2^{2024a}(c^{2024}+ 2^{2024(b-a)}d^{2024})=2^n.$$ Since the RHS is a power of $2$, both factors in the LHS are also powers of $2$ (possibly $2^0).$ $c^{2024}$ is an odd number, therefore $2^{2024(b-a)}d^{2024}$ which is at least $1$ is also an odd number. So $2024(b-a) =0$, therefore $a=b$. And $c^{2024}+ d^{2024}$ is equal to $2^k$ for some non-negative integer $k$.

Since $c$ and $d$ are odd, the number $c^{2024}+ d^{2024}$ equals $2$ modulo $4$. So $k=1$. Then $c=d=1$ and finally $x=y$.